# Не могу понять, почему запрос возвращает не тот результат, который я ожидал

Tags: sql, база-данных

Почему при выполнении запроса возвращается не тот результат, который я ожидал. Верное решение уже нашел, однако необходима помощь с объяснением того, почему не подходит вариант, указанный ниже.

Схема БД состоит из четырех таблиц:

```
Product(maker, model(PK), type),
PC(code(PK), model(FK к Product.model), speed, ram, hd, cd, price),
Laptop(code(PK), model(FK к Product.model), speed, ram, hd, price, screen),
Printer(code(PK), model(FK к Product.model), color, type, price).
```

Необходимо найти производителя(Product.maker), выпускающего ПК, но не выпускающего лэптопы.

Выполняю следующий запрос, однако он выводит список всех производителей, выпускающих ПК

```
    SELECT DISTINCT maker
    FROM Product
    WHERE 
        (model IN (SELECT model FROM PC)) AND
        (model NOT IN (SELECT model FROM Laptop));
```

Comment: Это учебное задание с сайта sql-ex.ru, которое нужно решать самостоятельно. А если вы решили задачу, то на форуме этого сайта задайте свой вопрос.

Comment: Любое условие в части where применяется к одной текущей строке. предположим у maker="A" есть две записи в таблице Product с model='PC' и с model='NOTE'. проверяем первую строку "PC" входит таблицу PC и "PC" не входит в таблицу Latop - все, условие совпало - выдаем строку на выход, проверяем вторую запись, она не входит в первую таблицу, но входит во вторую, условия не совпали, эту запись мы в результат не выдаем. Но производитель "A" все равно уже вернулся при проверке первой записи

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы запрашиваете все модели из таблицы `Product`, у которых:

а) указано что это ПК,

```
    (model IN (SELECT model FROM PC)) AND
```

И б) не указано что это ноутбук,

```
    (model NOT IN (SELECT model FROM Laptop))
```

Так как по условиям задачи модель не может быть одновременно ноутбуком и ПК, то эти два критерия являются взаимоисключающими. А значит ваш запрос можно упростить так, уб­рав вто­рую часть условия:

```
SELECT DISTINCT maker
FROM Product
WHERE 
    (model IN (SELECT model FROM PC))
```

Совершенно очевидно что такой запрос вернёт все модели типа ПК, отобрав из которых толь­ко имена производителей вы получите именно то, что наблюдаете: всех производителей хотя бы одного ПК.